# MySQL, using a joined table twice in the same query

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to write a MySQL query that joins two columns in the same table to another table. I have looked through many examples and tried a great many things, most of them just error for one reason or another.

I have a Teams table:

```
 ID | Team
 1  | Team 1
 2  | Team 2
 3  | Team 3
 4  | Team 4
```

I have a games table:

```
 ID | Team_1 | Team_2
  1  |  1     | 2
  2  |  2     | 3
  3  |  3     | 4
  4  |  4     | 1
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT PIO.Games.id
      , Team.Name AS `Team-1`
      , Team.Name AS `Team-2`
  FROM Games
  left 
  JOIN Team 
    ON Games.Team_1 = Team.id
  left 
  JOIN Team as T2 
    ON Games.Team_2 = Team.id
```

I need to list the games and show the team names, I expect:

```
Game_ID   Team-1     Team-2
  1    |     Team 1  |   Team 2
  2    |     Team 2  |   Team 3
  3    |     Team 3  |   Team 4
  4    |     Team 4  |   Team 1
```

But I'm getting the first team twice:

```
 Game_ID |  Team-1  |   Team-2
 1       |  Team 1  |   Team 1
 2       |  Team 2  |   Team 2
 3       |  Team 3  |   Team 3
 4       |  Team 4  |   Team 4
```

I've spent several hours so far on this and have come up with nothing that works! I assume it's something really simple I'm missing.

I have tried the solutions on a mySQL database in MAMP in both Navicat and SequelPro.

Anyone any ideas? All help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: The `JOIN` clauses tell the truth: you have two instances of the "Team" table. The second one is aliased as "T2" (`JOIN Team as T2`) and this makes the name "Team" to **not** identify it in the rest of the query. The first one is known as "Team" (because it doesn't have any alias). Read the rest of the query and think of the first instance of the table where it reads "Team" and to the second instance where it reads "T2" (nowhere, actually). The solution should be easy to find: use an alias ("T1") for the first instance of the table and replace "Team" with "T1" or "T2" in the rest of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the aliases you created. This will allow you to join the Team Table twice but won't confuse the db engine.

```
    SELECT g.id, t.Name AS Team-1, t2.Name AS Team-2
    FROM Games AS g
    LEFT JOIN Teams AS t ON g.Team_1 = t.ID
    LEFT JOIN Teams AS t2 ON g.Team_2 = t2.ID
```

Comment: Many thanks, this is similar to a few of the things I have tried earlier, unfortunately I get a: 'Unknown column 't.Team' in 'field list'' Error.

Comment: @user1814966     What is the name of that column in the table? You listed Team as the name of the column in the table schema but Name in your sql. Is it Name? Updated my answer to have Name as the column. You need to find out what the actual column name is though and fill that in.

Comment: Also if the table is Teams instead of Team then that could be the problem. Verify that the table names are correct and the column names are correct and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have solved, thanks for the help. Look like I had confused myself in the example! Substituted .Team for .Name and all seems to be well.

```
SELECT 
Games.id,
T1.Name AS "Team-1",
T2.Name AS "Team-2"

FROM Games 
left join Team as T1 on Games.Team_1 = T1.id
left join Team as T2 on Games.Team_2 = T2.id
```